# Set font custom searchview Android studio

Tags: android-studio, searchview

Select the custom font for search view:

```
searchView = (SimpleSearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

searchView.getSearchEditText().setTypeface(AppFontClass.getCurrentTypeFace(getApplicationContext()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 TextView searchText = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
 Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/myFont.ttf");
 searchText.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
```